# How to use MultinomialNB with MultiOutputClassifier and partial_fit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I could not find the answer to this question anywhere nor an example in scikit learn documentation for my particular case.

I want to use `MultinomialNB` with `MultiOutputClassifier` and partial_fit

I can't figure out the format of the class parameter of `partial_fit` function  (which is not required for `fit()` function, that works perfectly)

What am I missing here ?

Thanks for your help

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

df_train = pd.DataFrame({'feature': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]})

df_train_labels = pd.DataFrame({'class1': ['1-3', '1-3','1-3', '1-3', '4-5', '4-5', '4-5'], 'class2': ['1-2', '1-2', '3-5', '3-5', '3-5', '3-5', '3-5']})

prediction_model = MultiOutputClassifier(MultinomialNB())

prediction_model.fit(df_train, df_train_labels) # Works fine

prediction_model.partial_fit(df_train,\
                                 df_train_labels,\
                                 np.unique(df_train_labels))  # Error
```

ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got '1-2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes param value has to be a list of uniques values for each target variable.

From Documentation:

> classes : list of numpy arrays, shape (n_outputs).
> Each array is unique classes for one output in str/int
> Can be obtained by via
> `[np.unique(y[:, i]) for i in range(y.shape[1])]`, where y is the
> target matrix of the entire dataset.
>
> This argument is required for the first call to partial_fit
> and can be omitted in the subsequent calls.
> Note that y doesn't need to contain all labels in `classes`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np   

from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

df_train = pd.DataFrame({'feature': [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]})

df_train_labels = pd.DataFrame({'class1': ['1-3', '1-3','1-3', '1-3', '4-5', '4-5', '4-5'], 
                                'class2': ['1-2', '1-2', '3-5', '3-5', '3-5', '3-5', '3-5']})

prediction_model = MultiOutputClassifier(MultinomialNB())



classes = [df_train_labels[c].unique() for c in df_train_labels]
prediction_model.partial_fit(df_train,\
                             df_train_labels,\
                             classes) 
prediction_model.predict([[1],[8,]])
# array([['1-3', '3-5'],
#        ['1-3', '3-5']], dtype='<U3')
```